# incorrect syntax error in c#

Tags: sql-server-2008, c#-2.0

The following query is giving me an incorrect syntax error

```
dt = sFunctions.ExecuteQuery(Variables.con, "House_Machinery", "usp_housemachinery_Master_insert" + Id + ",'" + txtItemName.Text + "'," + txthp.Text + "," + txtrate.Text + "," + Variables.sTendercode + "," + Variables.StrResourceHeaderCode);
                sFunctions.setSqldbConnCommand_Close(sSqldbCommand);
```

The error is as follows:

```
incorrect syntax near ','
```

Does anyone have any insight as to the source of my problem?

its still having the same error.

Comment: This appears to be open to [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Comment: What is the value of `usp_housemachinery_Master_insert`?

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson its the name of a stored procedure

Comment: @kunaljangade Then you're at the least missing a space between the SP name and the id. You should probably just log the resulting SQL statement and manually verify that it's built correctly. Also, Oded's comment about SQL injection shouldn't be ignored, it will crash and burn if someone enters quotes in the text fields.

Answer (score 2):

You are missing a `"` just before `usp_housemachinery_Master_insert"`.

It should be:

```
sFunctions.ExecuteQuery(Variables.con, 
                       "House_Machinery", 
                       "usp_housemachinery_Master_insert" + ...
```

Note that string concatenation is an invitation for [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) - you should parameterize your queries.

---

The error might be coming from SQL Server - you need to check exactly what you are sending it - it may very well be invalid SQL, but without knowing the values of the different text boxes it is not possible to tell for sure.

Comment: hey i edited my anser but its still the same error on my screen

Comment: @kunaljangade - why did you edit your question to make all answers invalid?

Comment: @kunaljangade - You need to check the SQL that you produce with all that string concatenation - it is probably incorrect.

Comment: @kunaljangade - Then add details to the question - edit and add at the bottom, instead of completely changing it.